# Tomcat7: Possible to have different WebApp Context to name of WAR file?

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to deploy a WAR file called (say) 'myapp.war' to Tomcat 7 , such that the context is different from the WAR file ? So, even though my WAR file is called 'myapp' I want to access the URL as (eg) http://`localhost`/mycontent

Answer (score 3):

I've never really thought about doing that kind of rewriting in Tomcat itself.

For various reasons, scalability included, I usually set up Tomcat and Apache with mod_proxy so that Apache acts as a Reverse Proxy for the Tomcat instance, then you can do all the rewriting you like with Apache, instead of fiddling with Context names.